# Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++

I have 3 files namely concat.cpp, concat.h and test4concat.cpp, when i compile and execute i get the following error.
Enter the number of splits: 1 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

It asks for the first split and then stops, since i am fairly new to cpp i would need some help on this. Thanks

Following are the 3 file

concat.cpp

```
#include <iostream>                 
#include <cstring>                  
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "concat.h"


using namespace std;



char concat(char* si,char* w,char* fid)
{


    strcat (si,w);

    strcat (si,fid);

     return 0;
}
```

concat.h

```
#ifndef TRY_H_INCLUDED
#define TRY_H_INCLUDED

char concat(char* si,char* w,char* fid);


#endif
```

test4concat.cpp

```
#include <iostream>                 
#include <cstring>                  
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <concat.h>
using namespace std;


int main ()
 {
 char* si;
 char* w;
 char* fid;


cout << "Enter the number of splits: ";
cin >> si;
cout << "Enter the number of watchdogs: ";
cin >> w;
cout << "Enter the Fid: ";
cin >> fid;
concat(si, w, fid);
cout<<"\nThe string is "<< si <<endl;


}
```

Problem which i am encountering:

Enter the number of splits: 1 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Where does it segfault?  Can you use a debugger to find the line where it occurs?

Comment: If you're new to C++, why are you not using C++ constructs such as std::string?  What books or learning material are you using that have you start using char*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate memory using malloc (or new as you are writing in C++)  before reading data into si, w and fid.

```
si = new char[10];
w = new char[10];
fid = new char[10];
```

Of course you need to modify the sizes of the character arrays for your own requirements.

Comment: @user3444046 don't forget to call delete si, delete w, delete fid

Comment: Do not forget to use delete operator on the pointers after you no longer need these allocated spaces as others point out. You won't have problem in this specific example but if you were writing a  bigger program that uses lots of memory. These memory leaks may crash your program.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a way to do it in C++, avoiding all manual memory allocation pitfalls:

```
#include <iostream>                 
#include <string>                  

int main ()
{
  std::string si, w, fid;

  std::cout << "Enter the number of splits: ";
  std::cin >> si;
  std::cout << "Enter the number of watchdogs: ";
  std::cin >> w;
  std::cout << "Enter the Fid: ";
  std::cin >> fid;
  si += w;
  si += fid;
  std::cout<<"\nThe string is "<< si << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: return 0 can be added

Comment: @lizusek No need. Some people like that, but I don't think it adds anything here.

Comment: Thank u so much for your inputs, but i need the int main () in a separate file so had to call the function.

Comment: @user3444046 You can just put the code I showed in a function. Needing to use a function does not mean you have to write a broken one.

Answer (score 0):

"Enter the number of splits: ";

So you want a number, `int`.

```
int si;
cout << "Enter the number of splits: ";
cin >> si;
```

If you really want to read through pointer, first allocate memory to it with `operator new`:

```
int main() {
    char* pt = new char;
    cin >> pt;
    cout << (*pt);
    delete pt;
    return 0;
}
```

---

### C++

There is a `std::string` class being a `C++` string of characters, a specialization of `std::basic_string` with `char` as a template parameter. It is flexible and may be used in this case as well:

```
#include <iostream>                 
#include <string>                  

int main ()
{
  std::string si, w, fid;

  std::cout << "Enter the number of splits: ";
  std::cin >> si;
  std::cout << "Enter the number of watchdogs: ";
  std::cin >> w;
  std::cout << "Enter the Fid: ";
  std::cin >> fid;
  si += w;
  si += fid;

  std::cout<<"\nThe string is "<< si << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char` and `int` are compatible types, and this really doesn't address the main issue with the code.

Comment: Thank u so much for your inputs, but i need the int main () in a separate file so had to call the function.